# fetchColumn() failing on simple query, but fine on another

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need a second pair of eyes on this.  I can NOT figure out why this function works just fine:

```
function get_password($db, $id) {
  try {
    $sql = $db->prepare('SELECT password FROM employee 
                         WHERE employee.emp_id = ?');
    $sql->bindParam(1, $id);
    $sql->execute();
    $password = $sql->fetchColumn();
  } catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
  }

  return $password;
}
```

and this function fails on fetchColumn():

```
function get_name($db, $email) {
  try {
    $sql = $db->prepare('SELECT login
                         FROM employee
                         WHERE email = ?');
    $sql->bindParam(1, $email);
    $sql->execute();
    $user_name = $sql->fetchColumn(0);

  } catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
  }
  return $user_name;
}
```

I have verified the following:

- I am trimming the email, so no extra white space is in there
- the query works from the command line
- the prepare() statement is successful and errorInfo() returns nothing
- the bindParam() statement returns true and errorInfo() returns nothing
- the execute() statement returns 1 row and errorInfo() returns nothing
- the fetchColumn(0) statement returns False (ARGH!!!!) but errorInfo() still returns nothing.

I have also tried using just fetchColumn(), fetchAll, and other fetch attempts.

I have also tried re-writing in the SELECT to this:

```
'SELECT employee.login FROM employee WHERE employee.email = ?'
```

but results are the same.

Is there some concept here I'm missing?  Any other ideas of how I might debug this?

Comment: Out of curiosity: what happens if you execute directly the query from the php code without using prepared statement, can you fetch the results then?

Comment: **fetchColumn()** returns false when there is no row left to read. Did you dump the query string ? What is the email value ? No special characters or so ? Are you sure your console app and your web (I presume) app are using the same databse ?

Comment: Did you trim the email address before inserting it? Which collation do you use, is it case sensitive? Are you sure, that the email addresses you used to test from command line and the one used to test your app are the same (no typo, same case, same everything?).

Comment: If you insert `$sql->rowCount()` immediately after `$sql->execute()` and dump the value, what do you get? Note that you should actually be handling this use case, as right now you are just assuming that at least one row is returned (not a good assumption in your code).

Comment: @Shadow - Excellent suggestion.  I hard-coded the email in my code and it STILL failed.  So I tried again in Workspaces and it failed there too. (Yesterday I think it was also failing but I did not see it.)   I was using the wrong email!

Comment: - Thank you all for your ideas and suggestions.  Any of them would have got me attacking from another direction and seen that I had the wrong email.   I don't know if I should be relieved that the answer is so simple or bang my head on the wall because I spent all day on this.

Comment: @Mike Brant - I will also start checking my rowCounts().  Thank you for that tip.